# Magento 2: Error when listing customers or adding a new one

Tags: magento, azure, bitnami, magento2

First of all, I am not an expert on Magento, but have been working with it for the last 3 months.
I have just deployed an azure machine with Bitnami Magento 2.0.2.
Everything was going perfect but when I try to "register as a customer" on the frontend or even try to "list all the customers" on the backend, I get the same http content (error):

```
There has been an error processing your request
Class Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory does not exist
Error log record number: 1212123443869
```

I have no idea about what can be done.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Your questions a little scant on details -- so here's an overview of your situation and what **might** be causing your problem.

The class Magento can't find (`Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory`) is a factory class.  In Magento 2, factory classes are **automatically** created for you.  If you're running in `default` or `developer` mode, Magento will create these classes whenever it encounters them in the

```
var/generation
```

folder.  When Magento's set to `production` mode, it will **not** generate these classes.  Before you deploy to `production` mode, you need to run the command line

```
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

command.  This will automatically create any file you need in

```
var/generation
```

Base on the information you've provided, my first guesses would be

1. Your web server can't write to the `var/generation` folder, and when it fails to create a class, you get your error
2. Magento's running in `production` mode, and you didn't pr-generate your classes.

Comment: Alan, thanks for your attention, for some reason the files were not being generated on var/generation, you are right. I could not wait so I deployed another image from VM Depot. That one worked for the customers but its not currently working for subscribing to newsletters/listing newsletter subscribers. I am trying yo find out if is the same "compile" problems that you mentioned. BTW, Thanks for your help.

Comment: One important thing: I am using bitnami container.

Comment: @WagnerBertolini I couldn't speak to a specific vendor's implementation of a container project (docker) that, in my opinion, is still hasn't proven itself.  If I was deploying a Magento 2 system I'd look to a generic VPS, or ping Nexcess on their recommendation for Magento 2 hosting.